# Firestore Google Maps Marker setOnClickListerner problem in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

Can you guys help me out.

My code shows same document when I click a marker.

I think there problem in my for loop.
I am creating a list of parking spots and when clicked i would show the details of Parking spots in modal bottom sheet
here is my code.

```
public class ParkingSpace extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{


    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Parking parking;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference parkingRef = db.collection("Parking Lots");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parking_space);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(16.4023,120.5960);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,14));
        parkingRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                            parking = documentSnapshot.toObject(Parking.class);
                            parking.setDocumentId(documentSnapshot.getId());

                            String lat = parking.getLatitude();
                            String lon = parking.getLongitude();
                            String title = parking.getparkingName();
                            String owner = parking.getName();
                            String documentId= parking.getDocumentId();
                            double latd = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                            double lond = Double.parseDouble(lon);
                            LatLng location = new LatLng(latd,lond);


                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet("Owner: " +owner).position(location).title(title));

                            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
                                    parking = documentSnapshot.toObject(Parking.class);
                                    String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();

                                    Toast.makeText(ParkingSpace.this, "Document ID:" +documentId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("lat",lat);
                                    bottomSheet.setArguments(bundle);

                                    bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"bottomsheet");
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }

                });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are effectively using the same `Parking` instance ( `parking` ) for all markers because each iteration of the loop sets it to the value of the next query result.  So by the time the marker click event occurs the `parking` instance is the last one processed (for all markers).

An alternate approach is to associate a `parking` instance with the newly added marker and get that instance in the `onMarkerClick`.

Something like this:

```
// ... all your code up to this line remains same ....

// Here the `addMarker` method returns the newly added Marker to which we can associate
// any object needed - so associate the "parking" instance...

Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet("Owner: " +owner).position(location).title(title));
m.setTag(parking);
```

Then in your `onMarkerClick` replace:

```
parking = documentSnapshot.toObject(Parking.class);
```

with

```
// Use the associated Parking object (saved as a tag) to get needed info
Parking p = (Parking) marker.getTag();
if (p == null) {
   // some other marker on map 
   return;
}
String documentId = p.getDocumentId();
String lat = p.getLatitude();
// and any other data I may have missed should come from "p".
```